# Regex check for digits with decimal place

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal, repeat

I have a regex in place for checking a price being entered. The price can not be a 5 figure sum or more, but can contain an option decimal number. So -

- 1000 = allowed
- 9999.99 = allowed
- 10000 = not allowed
- 100.000 = not allowed

This is what I have so far, which is checking the number of decimals correctly, but isn't checking the amount of digits before the decimal place. What am I doing wrong?

```
var reg = new RegExp("^(\d{0,4})+(\.[0-9]{2})?$");
```

Comment: Why is 2nd one allowed and last one not?

Comment: The last one is not allowed because prices only have two decimal digits, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong quantifier

```
var reg = new RegExp("^(\d{0,4})(\.[0-9]{2})?$");
```

just remove the `+` and your regex is fine.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?335ig)

With this `(\d{0,4})+` you are repeating your first group, so you can match any amount of digits before the dot.

Your jsfiddle works for me, if I double escape

```
var reg = new RegExp("^\\d{0,4}(?:\\.\\d{2})?$");
```

or don't put your regex in a string

```
var reg = new RegExp(/^(\d{0,4})(\.[0-9]{2})?$/);
```

Comment: The regex should be changed to allow "1000.1" and disallow "" -> `^(\d{1,4})(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Comment: @Pharaoh no it shouldn't Prices always have two decimal places, never 1.

Comment: @Pharaoh, why? I can't see this requirement in the OPs question.

Comment: I know prices are always displayed with zero or two decimal places, but if the regex is parsing user input, I'd think about allowing "10.1" - the drawback are typos.

Comment: @stema: Right, that's not part of the question. I only wanted to hint at these two possibility, especially the empty string that goes through as a valid price. I guess that's why Joseph tried when he used `+` - making at least one digit necessary.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers. Looks like it works perfectly in RegExr, but I can't seem to implement it correctly now, driving me nuts. Made a fiddle with it (in AngularJS, hope you don't mind!) http://jsfiddle.net/WinterJoey/76hdU/

Comment: @stema I could vote up that updated answer for a lifetime. Thanks so much!